# How the synchronized_pool_resource actually works?

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator, c++pmr

I am studying about the polymorphic memory allocation in C++17.
I modified an example which uses monotonic_buffer_resource for vector allocations  to use a synchronized_pool_resource.
I detected a strange behavior. Specifically , there are many memory allocations , just for two additions  in the vector.  I did not run benchmarks but I think that this a huge penalty for the performance

The program was compiled using the O2
***g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic***

Below is the code

```
class debug_resource : public std::pmr::memory_resource {

public:
    explicit debug_resource(std::string name,
        std::pmr::memory_resource* up = std::pmr::get_default_resource())
        : _name{ std::move(name) }, _upstream{ up }
    { }

    void* do_allocate(size_t bytes, size_t alignment) override {
        std::cout << _name << " do_allocate(): " << bytes << '\n';
        void* ret = _upstream->allocate(bytes, alignment);
        return ret;
    }
    void do_deallocate(void* ptr, size_t bytes, size_t alignment) override {
        std::cout << _name << " do_deallocate(): " << bytes << '\n';
        _upstream->deallocate(ptr, bytes, alignment);
    }
    bool do_is_equal(const std::pmr::memory_resource& other) const noexcept override {
        return this == &other;
    }

private:
    std::string _name;
    std::pmr::memory_resource* _upstream;
};
int main()
{
  
    debug_resource default_dbg{ "default" };
    std::pmr::synchronized_pool_resource pool(&default_dbg);
  //  debug_resource dbg{ "pool", &pool };
    std::pmr::vector<std::string> strings{ &pool };

   strings.emplace_back("Hello Short String");
   strings.emplace_back("Hello Short String 2");
}
```

The console output is the following

default do_allocate(): 32
default do_allocate(): 528
default do_allocate(): 32
default do_allocate(): 528
default do_allocate(): 1000
default do_allocate(): 192
default do_allocate(): 968
default do_allocate(): 192

default do_deallocate(): 528
default do_deallocate(): 32
default do_deallocate(): 1000
default do_deallocate(): 192
default do_deallocate(): 968
default do_deallocate(): 192
default do_deallocate(): 528
default do_deallocate(): 32

Comment: to see extra allocations for strings you should use std::pmr::string as a type for elements, not std::string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the function description: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/synchronized_pool_resource

> It consists of a **collection of pools** that serves request for different
> block sizes. **Each pool manages a collection of chunks** that are then
> divided into blocks of uniform size.
>
> Calls to do_allocate are dispatched to the pool serving the smallest
> blocks accommodating the requested size.
>
> **Exhausting memory** in the pool causes the next allocation request for
> that pool **to allocate an additional chunk of memory** from the upstream
> allocator to replenish the pool. **The chunk size obtained increases
> geometrically**.
>
> **The largest block size and maximum chunk size may be tuned by passing
> a std::pmr::pool_options struct to its constructor.**

So a pool is actually a collection of memory blocks. And this collection is increased when necessary. Hence multiple allocations.

To decrease the number of allocations you can try playing with [std::pmr::pool_options](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pool_options).